# Magento - Changing the place of block to another page

Tags: magento-1.8, template, php, theme

I am using MA2 Juno theme and trying to move default checkout block to another place, like this:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

For this I figured out that I have to move this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBlock1') ?>
```

code block from header.phtml to topMenu.phtml

But after I changed, it didn't work. I think I need to tell somehow to Magento that topBlock1.phtml is ChildHtml of topMenu.phtml. But I don't know how.

After a very long Google search I saw that I have to do something in local.xml file.

I did something like this but it didn't work. Can you guys help me ?

```
<reference name="topMenu">
        <block name="top.block1" template="page/html/topBlock1.phtml" type="page/html_topblock1" as="topBlock1">
          <label>Top1 blocks</label>
        </block>
</reference>
```

PS: CSS file changes are not important I know how to edit those and override.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of xml you mentioned in the question should work, but you need to change something.
The topmenu is rendered by the template `page/html/topmenu.phtml`. You need to add in that template file this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBlock1') ?>
```

or better yet:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

in case you need to add other blocks also.